# Responsive layout like table

Tags: css

I want to make a layout like this, above picture for wide screen and below for small screen. Please suggest me how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Please post your attempt with your question.

Comment: I suggest you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this is you are using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/),

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                green space...give height as required
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                button
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                button
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No, I want to transform picture 1 to picture 2

Comment: are you using bootstrap for responsive?

Comment: so do you want the above work for large and medium, and the lower for small?